same loss and accuracy for all epochs
I have a dataset of the handwritten words - "TRUE", "FALSE" and "NONE".I want my model to recognize the words and put them in the correct class. I created a simple CNN model copying the TinyVGG architecture. However, the loss and accuracy values are the same for all epochs. I tried changing the batch size, epochs and learning rate and it's not working. What changes should I make to the model?
class CUSTOMDATASETV2(nn.Module):
  
    def __init__(self, input_shape: int, hidden_units: int, output_shape: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.block_1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=input_shape, 
                      out_channels=hidden_units, 
                      kernel_size=3, # how big is the square that's going over the image?
                      stride=1, # default
                      padding=1),# options = "valid" (no padding) or "same" (output has same shape as input) or int for specific number 
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=hidden_units, 
                      out_channels=hidden_units,
                      kernel_size=3,
                      stride=1,
                      padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2,
                         stride=2) # default stride value is same as kernel_size
        )
        self.block_2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(hidden_units, hidden_units, 3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(hidden_units, hidden_units, 3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2)
        )
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Flatten(),
            # Where did this in_features shape come from? 
            # It's because each layer of our network compresses and changes the shape of our inputs data.
            nn.Linear(in_features=hidden_units*16*16, 
                      out_features=output_shape)
        )
    
    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor):
        x = self.block_1(x)
        # print(x.shape)
        x = self.block_2(x)
        # print(x.shape)
        x = self.classifier(x)
        # print(x.shape)
        return x

torch.manual_seed(42)
model_2 = CUSTOMDATASETV2(input_shape=3, 
    hidden_units=10, 
    output_shape=len(class_names)).to(device)
model_2



from tqdm.auto import tqdm
torch.manual_seed(42)

# Measure time
from timeit import default_timer as timer
train_time_start_model_2 = timer()

# Train and test model 
epochs = 10
for epoch in tqdm(range(epochs)):
    print(f"Epoch: {epoch}\n---------")
    train_step(data_loader=train_dataloader, 
        model=model_2, 
        loss_fn=loss_fn,
        optimizer=optimizer,
        accuracy_fn=accuracy_fn,
        device=device
    )
    test_step(data_loader=test_dataloader,
        model=model_2,
        loss_fn=loss_fn,
        accuracy_fn=accuracy_fn,
        device=device
    )

train_time_end_model_2 = timer()
total_train_time_model_2 = print_train_time(start=train_time_start_model_2,
                                           end=train_time_end_model_2,
                                           device=device)

def train_step(model: torch.nn.Module,
               data_loader: torch.utils.data.DataLoader,
               loss_fn: torch.nn.Module,
               optimizer: torch.optim.Optimizer,
               accuracy_fn,
               device: torch.device = device):
    train_loss, train_acc = 0, 0
    model.to(device)
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(data_loader):
        # Send data to GPU
        X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)

        # 1. Forward pass
        y_pred = model(X)
        y_pred_prob = torch.softmax(y_pred, dim=1).argmax(dim=1)

        # 2. Calculate loss
        loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
        train_loss += loss
        train_acc += accuracy_fn(y_true=y,
                                 y_pred=y_pred_prob) # Go from logits -> pred labels

        # 3. Optimizer zero grad
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # 4. Loss backward
        loss.backward()

        # 5. Optimizer step
        optimizer.step()

    # Calculate loss and accuracy per epoch and print out what's happening
    train_loss /= len(data_loader)
    train_acc /= len(data_loader)
    print(f"Train loss: {train_loss:.5f} | Train accuracy: {train_acc:.2f}%")

def test_step(data_loader: torch.utils.data.DataLoader,
              model: torch.nn.Module,
              loss_fn: torch.nn.Module,
              accuracy_fn,
              device: torch.device = device):
    test_loss, test_acc = 0, 0
    model.to(device)
    model.eval() # put model in eval mode
    # Turn on inference context manager
    with torch.inference_mode():
        for X, y in data_loader:
            # Send data to GPU
            X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)

            # 1. Forward pass
            test_pred = model(X)
            test_pred_prob = torch.softmax(test_pred, dim=1).argmax(dim=1)

            # 2. Calculate loss and accuracy
            test_loss += loss_fn(test_pred, y)
            test_acc += accuracy_fn(y_true=y,
                y_pred=test_pred_prob # Go from logits -> pred labels
            )

        # Adjust metrics and print out
        test_loss /= len(data_loader)
        test_acc /= len(data_loader)
        print(f"Test loss: {test_loss:.5f} | Test accuracy: {test_acc:.2f}%\n")


You are using train_loss += loss to accumulate your loss. If you are doing gradient computations, this will use a lot of memory as it needs to save the gradient of each entry in the epoch. You may want to use train_loss += loss.item() instead. Also, lake sure you are calculating your loss function with gradients.

can you show it in code if you don't mind

What do you want me to show? What is your loss_fn?

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

Looks like the problem is in this line
y_pred_prob = torch.softmax(y_pred, dim=1).argmax(dim=1)

It should be without the argmax function. Argmax returns the indices of the maximum value of all elements in the input tensor whereas softmax provides the probability. Try it without argmax as following:
y_pred_prob = torch.softmax(y_pred, dim=1)

For accuracy you can add the argmax function
train_acc += accuracy_fn(y_true=y,
                             y_pred=y_pred_prob.argmax(dim=1))

You might have to change the loss function to accommodate this change.
